# How to set Query Params to all my routes when it changes - in EMBER

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I have a route and a dynamic sub-route. I have defined a queryParams for my sub-route {queryParams: { start: 5 }}. By default the queryParam is set as 5. 
So my routes will be:

```
#/folders/1
#/folders/2
#/folders/3
```

Now dynamically I change the queryParams of a subRoute as {queryParams: { start: 10 }}. 
Now the current subRoutes will be:

```
#/folders/1?start=10
#/folders/2
#/folders/3
```

After changing the queryParams of a subRoute then visiting other subRoute I need to set queryParams of all the subRoute to "10".

```
#/folders/1?start=10
#/folders/2?start=10
#/folders/3?start=10
```

How can I change the queryParams of all the routes when its changing.

@Template:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="folders">
    <ul>
        {{#each item in model}}
            <li>{{#link-to 'folder' item.f_id}}{{item.f_name}} {{/link-to}}</li>
        {{/each}}
    </ul>

    <input type="button" value="Set Start Params" {{action "setStartParams"}}>
    {{outlet}}
</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="folder">
    This is folder listing of Folder {{model.id}}
</script>
```

@JS Code:

```
App.Router.map(function() {
    this.resource('folders', function(){
        this.resource('folder', {path: '/:id'});
    });
});

App.FoldersRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function() {
        return [{'f_name': 'folder1', 'f_id': '1'}, {'f_name': 'folder2', 'f_id': '2'}, {'f_name': 'folder3', 'f_id': '3'}];
    },
    actions:{
        setStartParams: function(){
            this.transitionTo({queryParams: {start: '10'}} );
        }
    }
});
```

JSBIN [Link](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/kixusunize/1/)

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK in Ember it is possible to change the routes dynamically